# I am trying to combine a JSON file to create markers in a google maps

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I think my JSON file is syntactically correct. and the code for that is below

```
{
 "locations": [
 {
    "latitude": 38.558961, 
    "longitude": -121.423011,
    "name": "AIRC",
    "title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
  },
{
    "latitude": 38.562605, 
    "longitude": -121.419683,
    "name": "GUY WEST",
    "title": "PRESIDENT?"
},
{
    "latitude": 38.556652, 
    "longitude": -121.423842,
    "name": "well",
    "title": "WORKOUT"
  },
{
    "latitude": 38.555465, 
    "longitude": -121.422551,
    "name": "Hornetsatdium",
    "title": "FOOTBAL!"
}

]}
```

I am trying to use GeoJson to add the Json file above into the google maps api below. I want to turn those json objects into markers. I am a novice when it comes to Json and even google maps. I am not exactly sure how to turn my json ojects into markers though

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 38.55914, lng: -121.423473},
            zoom: 16,
            disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('file:///GOOGLE_MAPS_JAVASCIPT/csus_locations.JSON');
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715119/google-maps-load-markers-from-json?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)

To be parsed by `map.data.loadGeoJson` it must have a top level `Feature` or `FeatureCollection`

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 is putting this error message in the console:
`Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection`

**code snippet demonstrating the error message:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.data.addGeoJson(jsonData);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var jsonData = {
  "locations": [{
      "latitude": 38.558961,
      "longitude": -121.423011,
      "name": "AIRC",
      "title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
    }, {
      "latitude": 38.562605,
      "longitude": -121.419683,
      "name": "GUY WEST",
      "title": "PRESIDENT?"
    }, {
      "latitude": 38.556652,
      "longitude": -121.423842,
      "name": "well",
      "title": "WORKOUT"
    }, {
      "latitude": 38.555465,
      "longitude": -121.422551,
      "name": "Hornetsatdium",
      "title": "FOOTBAL!"
    }

  ]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**code snippet with JSON converted to valid GeoJSON:**

```js
var map;
var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -40)
});

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.56, -121.425),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonData);
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    infoWin.setContent(event.feature.getProperty('name') + "<br>" + event.feature.getProperty('title'));
    infoWin.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
    infoWin.open(map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var geoJsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    /*        "latitude": 38.558961,
            "longitude": -121.423011,
            "name": "AIRC",
            "title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
*/
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-121.423011, 38.558961]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "AIRC",
      "title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    /*
        "latitude": 38.562605,
            "longitude": -121.419683,
            "name": "GUY WEST",
            "title": "PRESIDENT?"
*/
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-121.419683, 38.562605]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "GUY WEST",
      "title": "PRESIDENT?"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    /*
        "latitude": 38.556652,
            "longitude": -121.423842,
            "name": "well",
            "title": "WORKOUT"
*/
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-121.423842, 38.556652]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "well",
      "title": "WORKOUT"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    /*
        "latitude": 38.555465,
            "longitude": -121.422551,
            "name": "Hornetsatdium",
            "title": "FOOTBAL!"
*/
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-121.422551, 38.555465]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Hornetsatdium",
      "title": "FOOTBAL!"
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```